# Ehcache cache .data files have escaped unicode characters

Tags: windows, ehcache, datastore

My caches' data filenames seem to contain escaped unicode characters in the data store. Strangely only capital letters in the cache names are replaced. Eg:

> %004c%004f%0043%0041%004c%004dodifier%004cinking%004danager.data

Should be:

> LOCALModifierLinkingManager.data

Why is this the case? How can I fix it?

Environment: Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot fix this, it is by design. It comes from the fact that while cache names are case sensitive, some file systems are not. So Ehcache will always escape capital letters in the filenames to prevent collisions.

The easiest if you really want clear names is to not use capital letters.

Comment: Here's a JIRA ticket confirming: https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-1074